# Android Image Button does not show

Tags: java, android, xml

The image button does not show up in my app, but the button is still clickable its click log works.

This is the button:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/stopStream"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cancel_btn"
    android:contentDescription="@string/stop_stream"
    android:onClick="hangup"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Android Studio does show the drawable icon and the left toolbar, so the path of the image is correct. 
First I thought of having a wrong z-index (I come from the web world).
But there is not a real z-index to give a tag in android as far as I read.
What could further cause this issue

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context="de.app.test.VideoChatActivity">

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/gl_surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stopStream"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cancel_btn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/stop_stream"
        android:onClick="hangup"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switchCameraBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stopStream"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/send"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switchBtn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/switchCameraBtn"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:background="@drawable/call_btn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/send" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawable_mod"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawing1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="@string/drawing_one" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you see the `call_btn` file in the `drawable` folder in `Android Studio`?

Comment: i think your cancel_btn icon is black so it's invisible on a black background

Answer (score 1):

Try using src to set your icon to ImageButton, like

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stopStream"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cancel_btn"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/stop_stream"
        android:onClick="hangup"
        android:visibility="visible" />

//used background="@null" to set the image button background as null to only show the icon which was set with the src.
```